# how to back from third viewController to first viewcontroller?

Tags: iphone

I've a problem that I move from first viewcontroller to third viewcontroller by pushviewcontroller but when i do popViewControllerAnimated it comes to second viewcontroller but I need to come to first. pls some one help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use popToViewController as follows

```
 [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:o] animated:YES];
```

and similarly you can also use following statement to reach directly to first view controller where you started.

```
 [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think the latter approach would be preferred, since it does not require manual access to the UINavigationController's internal view hierarchy, even though the end result is the same.

Answer (score 2):

```
[[self navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```